# Google font icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

can we use both `google font` and `font awesome icon` in the same html page?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Yes, what's wrong in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you asking but of course you can. Google fonts are for your fonts (font-family) and font awesome is for icons.

Example:

Google font

```
h1{
font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

Font Awesome

```
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
```